# Why is my tiedot DB pointer nil?

Tags: go, tiedot

```
var myDB *db.DB

func init() {
    myDB, err := db.OpenDB("db")
    if err := myDB.Create("Feeds"); err != nil {}
    if err := myDB.Create("Votes"); err != nil {}
}

func idb() {
    for _, name := range myDB.AllCols() {
        fmt.Printf("I have a collection called %s\n", name)
    }    
}

func main() {
    idb()
}
```

I get the following error:

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

It is probably because `myDB` is `nil`, but why and how can I fix it so I can setup myDB in init?

Note that if I just drop everything in main without using a global variable, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> ```
> ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer
>   expressions but no types:
>
> ```
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
> ```

`myDB` is a local `init` function variable. `:=` is a short variable declaration.

```
myDB, err := db.OpenDB("db")
```

To update package `myDB` variable, write,

```
var err error
myDB, err = db.OpenDB("db")
```

Comment: ok I was thinking because of err did not exist yet i needed the :=